# PropertyInfo into Expression<Func<PropertyType>>

Tags: c#

I try to make an expression with a `PropertyInfo`. The expression should look like:

> Expression < Func < PropertyType >>

I need this Expression for this:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/8d46b3a64ea784c95dddeb9d421c7cda6de993a2/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/ValidationMessage.cs

The For property needs this kind of Expression.

Can anyone direct me to some links how to get this kind of Expression?

```
var entity = new Entity;  
var propertyInfo = entity.GetType().GetProperty("OneProperty");

var expr = GetExpression(propertyInfo);
// could be:
// Expression<Func<string>> or Expression<Func<int>>
```

edited;

Comment: BTW your code won't compile.

Comment: Do you want  a delegate to the property `"OneProperty"`? What does that property return? Please provide at least the code containing that property.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to achieve? It's possible to build an `Expression` dynamically (by invoking the various methods of, well, `Expression`) but if you need a *statically typed instance* of `Expression`, that won't do.

Comment: If you need a property acceessor, wouldn't you need an `Expression<Func<Entity, PropertyType>>`?

Comment: What do you want to do with the expression? Are you sure you need an expression, or could it just be a `Func`?

Answer (score 2):

If you need a property accessor for a property name given as string, you must also pass it the the object as parameter. Therefore you need an

```
Expression<Func<Entity, PropertyType>>
```

This function creates such an expression:

```
private static LambdaExpression CreatePropertyGetterExpression(Type entityType,
                                                               string propertyName)
{
    PropertyInfo property = entityType.GetProperty(propertyName);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "e");
    var body = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    return Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
}
```

This overload allows you to pass the entity type as generic parameter:

```
private static LambdaExpression CreatePropertyGetterExpression<TEntity>(string propertyName)
{
    return CreatePropertyGetterExpression(typeof(TEntity), propertyName);
}
```

This test

```
var expr = CreatePropertyGetterExpression<Entity>("OneProperty");
Console.WriteLine(expr);
Console.WriteLine(expr.GetType());
```

prints (assuming `OneProperty` to be of type `int`):

> e => e.OneProperty
> System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[MyProject.Entity, System.Int32]]

---

You can get an `Expression<Func<PropertyType>>` if you capture a variable like this:

```
Entity e = new Entity { PropertyOne = 42 };
Expression<Func<int>> expr = () => e.PropertyOne;
```

But how do you want to capture a variable if you are constructing an expression dynamically? This is not possible.

---

I found this [HtmlHelperValidationExtensions.ValidationMessageFor Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelpervalidationextensions.validationmessagefor?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_HtmlHelperValidationExtensions_ValidationMessageFor__2_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_IHtmlHelper___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___System_String_System_Object_) doing what you need:

```
public static IHtmlContent ValidationMessageFor<TModel,TResult> (
    this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel,TResult>> expression,
    string message,
    object htmlAttributes);
```

You can pass it the `Expression<Func<TModel,TResult>>` expression from above! However, you must know the result type in advance. Otherwise you will have to use reflection to call it.

Comment: i need the expression for this:  
[link](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/8d46b3a64ea784c95dddeb9d421c7cda6de993a2/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/ValidationMessage.cs)

The public property "For" needs an Expression<Func<T>> .
I have a list of propertyinfos and want to pass them somehow to the "For" Property

Comment: A lambda expression can capture a variable instead of having a parameter passed. But how do you want to realize this for a constructed expression? Where should a reference to the entity come from? `Entity e = new Entity();  Expression<Func<T>> expr = () => e.PropertyOne;`

Comment: I have a local Entity and a PropertyInfo:  `Expression<Func<T>> expr = () => (T)PropertyInfo.GetValue(Entity)`.     But with this i get an ArgumentException: The provided expression contains a UnaryExpression which is not supported

Comment: Thank you for your help so far!
Unfortunatly i need to use the other For Method because i'm working with Blazor.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution while trying to bind blazor inputs dynamically:

```
Entity e = new Entity { PropertyOne = 42 };
Expression<Func<int>> expr = () => e.PropertyOne;
```

to get the expression for this statement you should use a constant expression:

```
var e = new Entity() { PropertyOne = 42 };
var property = typeof(Entity).GetProperty("PropertyOne");
var entityType = typeof(Entity);
var parameter = Expression.Constant(e);
var body = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);

var resultToReturn = Expression.Lambda<func<TValue>>(body);
```

best regards.

Comment: it worked for me but The Type Parameter of Expression.Lambda was throwing an error, so I did Expression.Lambda(body)   only